# Pygame offset a grid made out of rectangles

Tags: python, pygame

I have this grid that I draw using `pygame`:

[image: Grid]
As you can see, it starts off at the top left corner. I draw it like this:

```
import pygame

# Color vars here

# Grid vars
WIDTH = 4
HEIGHT = 4
MARGIN = 1

# Initialize pygame
pygame.init()
WINDOW_SIZE = [820, 620]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # Set the screen background
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # Draw the grid
    for row in range(120):
        for column in range(160):
            # Set the color here

            # Draw rectangle
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, [
                (MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN,
                (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN, WIDTH, HEIGHT])

    # Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

    # Update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()

# Prevent hang if idle
pygame.quit()
```

How can I offset the grid so it doesn't start off at the top left? I want to move it right and down a bit. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add `offset_x` and `offset_y` to all elements when you draw them.

Comment: all create `pygame.Surface()` and `draw` on this surface instead of `screen` and at the end blit surface on screen with offset. `screen.blit(surface, (offset_x, offset_y))`

Comment: Thank you both! Got it to work using `screen.blit()` function as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As furas mentioned in the comments, there are two ways to go about:

#### 1. Add offset to the elements

If you want to move all elements, for example 16 pixels in x-axis and 32 pixels in y-axis, you could add the offset for every element.

```
offset_x, offset_y = 16, 32
for row in range(120):
    for column in range(160):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, [(MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN + offset_x, 
                                         (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN + offset_y, 
                                          WIDTH, HEIGHT])
```

---

One thing to look for when doing nested loops are calculations that can be moved outside the loop ([Loop-invariant code motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion)). For example, `MARGIN + WIDHT`, `MARGIN + offset_x`, `MARGIN + HEIGHT` and `MARGIN + offset_y` are the same for every iteration. If we calculate the value before the loop we'll save 4 * 120 * 160 = 76,800 computations each frame.

```
full_width, full_height = MARGIN + WIDHT, MARGIN + HEIGHT
offset_x, offset_y = 16 + MARGIN, 32 + MARGIN
for row in range(120):
    for column in range(160):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, [full_width * column + offset_x, 
                                         full_height * row + offset_y, WIDTH, HEIGHT])
```

---

If the offset you want is a factor of 6 (the size of a rectangle including the margin), let say 6 * 5 = 30, you could instead start the loop at index 5 and get rid off the offset values.

```
full_width, full_height = MARGIN + WIDHT, MARGIN + HEIGHT
for row in range(5, 125):
    for column in range(5, 165):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, [full_width * column + MARGIN, 
                                         full_height * row + MARGIN, WIDTH, HEIGHT])
```

### 2. Create a Surface

Instead of drawing directly on the screen (which is a Surface object) you could create a new Surface object of the size of your grid, draw on it and then blit it at the offset you want.

```
rows, columns = 120, 160
grid_image = pygame.Surface((rows * (WIDTH + 2 * MARGIN), columns * (HEIGHT + 2 * MARGIN)))
```

And inside the main loop.

```
full_width, full_height = MARGIN + WIDHT, MARGIN + HEIGHT
for row in range(rows):
    for column in range(columns):
        pygame.draw.rect(grid_image, color, [full_width * column + MARGIN, 
                                             full_height * row + MARGIN, WIDTH, HEIGHT])


screen.blit(grid_image, (offset_x, offset_y))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the in-depth answer! Learned a lot from this. I moved the`for` loop where I draw the rectangles outside of the main loop and it still works fine. Why is that?

Comment: Because when you're drawing on the screen it won't disappear until you overwrite it with something else. If your screen is static it would be preferred to have the drawing/blitting outside the main loop, but if it's going to be animated you might need to redraw it depending on what changes.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Makes a lot more sense.